# Export using Django admin import-export give me error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-import-export

I have installed a import-export extension in my app django, setting the admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Materiale
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources


class MaterialeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Materiale

class MaterialeAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = MaterialeResource

admin.site.register(Materiale, MaterialeAdmin)
```

All works perfectly, but when I have tried to click on the export button, django give me the following error:

```
Invalid format string
```

Here the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\widgets.py", line 183, in render
    return self.clean(value).strftime(self.formats[0])

During handling of the above exception (Invalid format string), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py", line 482, in export_action
    export_data = self.get_export_data(file_format, queryset, request=request)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py", line 460, in get_export_data
    data = resource_class(**self.get_export_resource_kwargs(request)).export(queryset, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 900, in export
    data.append(self.export_resource(obj))
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 855, in export_resource
    return [self.export_field(field, obj) for field in self.get_export_fields()]
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 855, in <listcomp>
    return [self.export_field(field, obj) for field in self.get_export_fields()]
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 849, in export_field
    return field.export(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\fields.py", line 125, in export
    return self.widget.render(value, obj)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\widgets.py", line 185, in render
    return datetime_safe.new_date(value).strftime(self.formats[0])
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datetime_safe.py", line 19, in strftime
    return strftime(self, fmt)
  File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datetime_safe.py", line 75, in strftime
    return super(type(dt), dt).strftime(fmt)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/magazzino/materiale/export/
Exception Value: Invalid format string
```

Answer (score 0):

Your export is trying to format a date object into a string, but this is failing.

- Have you set `settings.DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`, and does this contain a valid date format?  Try removing this setting and it should use the default.
- Presumably the db field it's trying to render is a valid date - can you add some debug to check what this field value is?

Check out the documentation for [`DateTimeWidget`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.DateTimeWidget).